# Playing music via streaming from the URL in an API using React Native and Expo

Tags: react-native, url, audio, expo

I'm opening this discussion in case someone can help me with this little issue I'm facing. Expo Go has its audio playback library, audio-av, but the problem is that it only plays direct links to .mp3 files. An official API doesn't provide access to the file's URI, but rather an online streaming link. In my search, I found that react-native-track-player does offer that possibility, but unfortunately, it's not compatible with Expo Go. Do you know of any way or library that is compatible with Expo Go and provides the option to play API links? I'm looking forward to your input.

This is what I get when I try with react-native-track-player or react-native-sound:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsAndroid' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes